# About isEqual and hash

Tags: objective-c, hash

This question is about the selector `isEqual` in objc.

I know when object use `isEqual`, they compared `hash`, but how to understand the follow code:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1];
NSLog(@"%d", [@"1" hash] == [string hash]); // output 1
```

I read the hash of object can not be same, why output is 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know when object use `isEqual`, they compared `hash`

That's not correct. `isEqual` compares the object without using the `hash` (usually).

> I read the hash of object can not be same

Also not correct, hashes **must** be equal for equal objects and **can** be the same for in-equal objects. As hash is an int, there are only 2^32 possible values, not enough for it to be unique for each possible object (unless that object is equivalent to 32 bits or less itself).

The only rule about `hash` is: If `[a isEqual:b]` is true, then this **must** also be true: `[a hash] == [b hash]`.

So as your two strings are equal, both `"1"`, then it follows that the hashes should also be equal.

Comment: There is a question about the causality between `isEqual` and `hash`. Is `isEqual` make `hash` equal stand up? Or,cause `hash` is equal comes to `isEqual`?

Comment: isEqual true implies hash true. Only.

Comment: but the memory address of `@"1"` and `string` is not same, we can not say the object is same, why `isEqual` give me a same result?

Comment: Because isEqual is not the same as saying these objects are the same. Real life example: My hat might be equal to your hat, but they are not the same hat.

Comment: o, I misunderstand `isEqual`.Thank you so much. And you can understand my description, that makes me respect.